# Embed connections between classes in MDriven

Tags: uml, modeling, mdriven

When creating the connections between two classes in UML (using MDriven), I inserted the correct values in each end (e.g. `0..*`). However, when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, an `(e)` appeared after the values. I found out, that it stands for "embed".

Which end of the connection should be "embed" in certain situations and why?

Comment: You should add a picture. This way the question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed is best explained as "in which table is the foreign key placed"
This is often self-evident:

- One-to-Many - foreign key will go in many end.
- Many-to-Many - foreign key will go into link-class(possibly implicit)
- One-to-One - This is where Embed-flag becomes important, because it is optional where to put the foreign key.

If you do not know what end to pick - you can just pick any of them.
But as you grow more experienced you might want to have the ability to control this.